# Speedup MYSQL(8.0.13) Restore from .sql file

Tags: mysql, restore

I am receiving .SQL(500mb) backup file and restoring to MYSQL (8.0.13) database.

Currently, restore is taking 5 hrs to complete. I would like to speedup the process and started working on it.

Here are the things I tried

1. Changed innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 from 1.
2. Changed expire_log_days from 0 to 2. My log was filling up and storing file for everyday.
3. My .sql file already have Unique key,Foreign key checks to zero.AutoCommit=0 like below

   /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
   /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
   /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

Here are my my.ini file settings

```
 max_connections=151
 table_open_cache=2000 
tmp_table_size=172M
 thread_cache_size=10 
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
 myisam_sort_buffer_size=334M 
key_buffer_size=8M
 read_buffer_size=64K
 read_rnd_buffer_size=256K 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
 innodb_log_buffer_size=1M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
 innodb_log_file_size=48M 
Innodb_thread_concurrency=17
 innodb_autoextend_increment=64 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
 innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000 
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
 innodb_open_files=300 i
nnodb_stats_on_
metadata=0
 innodb_file_per_table=1 
flush_time=0 
join_buffer_size=256K
 max_allowed_packet=4M 
max_connect_errors=100 
open_files_limit=4161
 sort_buffer_size=256K
 table_definition_cache=1400
```

frustrating part is sometimes restore is stuck for hours and I have to kill the connection.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innodb_buffer_pool_size should be closer to 1G rather than 8M

also increase innodb_log_file_size to 256M as the default 48M is a bit slow.

A innodb_log_buffer_size of 48M would help rather than a very small 1M.

Comment: I have followed your recommendations and performance improved at least 2x times. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but I'm disappointed its only 2x. Look at including advice in other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- I would advice to use 8.0.17 or above, so many bugs are fixed after 8.0.17 version.
- Disable the transaction extraction algorithm, as it is of no use unless you are doing group replication.

`transaction_write_set_extraction..... OFF`